# Font Size with php and/or CSS

Tags: php, css, font-size

I am trying to produce an effect where I have a title on a page all in Capitals.  I would however like to see the first character of each word with a slightly larger font size.

For example:

MY TITLE

The M and T would be in size 16 font and the rest of the word would be in size 12.  I am pulling the titles from a database (MySQL) so "MY TITLE" is just an example.  It could be any wording.

I realise there is a way to do this using substr (in php) and search for where the spaces are at the end of each word.  But this seems to me as though it will get a bit messy with coding.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$text = "My Title";
$newText = preg_replace('/(\w)(\w+\b)/', '<span class="firstLetter">$1</span>$2', $text);

echo $newText;  // <span class="firstLetter">M</span>y <span class="firstLetter">T</span>itle
```

**CSS**

```
.firstLetter{font-size: 125%;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CSS first letter pseudo-element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter) by wrapping each first letter in a `<span>` tag:

```
p span:first-letter
{ 
    font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Comment: That will increase only the FIRST letter in "MY TITLE" and not in each word

Comment: That effects only the M, not T. Edit. I was 5 seconds late.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: That still needs the messing with `substr` and wrapping the letters with `span` - in that case there is no benefit of using the CSS3 selector, which won't work in IE

Comment: This answer doesn't address how to add those `<span>` tags around the first letter of each word from text that comes from a database.

Comment: @AndrewR I don't think they were looking for that in their question

Answer (score 1):

Pure PHP solution:

```
<?php
$str = '<h2><big>S</big>ome <big>t</big>ext</h2>';
echo strtoupper($str);
?>
```

CSS Solution:

```
<h2><span class="larger">S</span>ome <span class="larger">T</span>ext</h2>
<style type="text/css">
h2{text-transform:uppercase;}
.larger{font-size:larger;}
</style>
```

**ADDITIONAL METHOD:** If you want to be able to output a particular format with a variable number of words, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$string = 'VariaBle Number oF WORds!';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$modified = array();
foreach($words as $word)
{
    $modified[] = '<big>'.substr($word, 0, 1).'</big>'.substr($word, 1, strlen($word));
}
echo strtoupper(implode(' ', $modified));
?>
```

Comment: you don't need PHP for what you're doing :) The question was to have a function that can transform ANY text accordingly, not just a hardcoded string

Comment: Aaaaaaaand I just noticed the addendum in the question. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS property,

```
font-variant:small-caps;
```